# Read information from Twitch's API and execute actions depending on the output

Tags: ethernet

i'm trying to create a display that notifies me when someone goes live on twitch. I need to acess the API and check if the 'stream' object is null or not. Then, perform an action depending on this.

The address to the API is http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/pedrinholuizf

What can I do? I'm using an Arduino Leonardo with the Ethernet Shield.

Answer (score 2):

Break your problem into small steps and try to identify the success criteria for each step. So you might:

1. Try to set up the Ethernet shield and get it to respond to a ping on your local network.
2. Try to connect to a site outside of your network.
3. See if you can find some examples of using the Twitch API.
4. Try to replicate one of the simple examples.
5. See if you can get the Stream object that you want.
6. See if you can read the value of the object.

If you have a plan and try to follow it you'll be able to tell us what you've been doing and where you got stuck / confused. That is likely to get you better answers – both because we can be more specific and also because we can see that you're "carrying your weight" as we work on the problem.